# Ayuda para formular una pregunta sobre cómo guardar parámetros de un método en una variable

Tags: discusión, soporte, revisión-de-pregunta

Quisiera saber cuál debe ser la pregunta apropiada al siguiente tema:

- **Guardar parámetros de un método en una variable**

Tengo el siguiente código que forma parte de una clase que maneja los eventos de un **frame**:

```java
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if(ae.getSource()== NuevoEstudiante.btnGuardar){

        String nombre= nuevoEstudiante.txtNombre.getText();
        String materia= nuevoEstudiante.txtMatricula.getText();
        String nota= nuevoEstudiante.txtNota.getText();

        String datos= DAO.guardar(
            new Estudiante(nombre, materia, Integer.parseInt(nota))
        );

        if(datos!= null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, datos);
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro Erroneo.");               
        }
    }
}
```

Cuando intento guardar los parámetros recibidos en la variable datos:

```java
String datos= DAO.guardar(new Estudiante(nombre, materia, Integer.parseInt(nota)));
```

... *NetBeans* me da un error diciéndome:

> incompatible types: void cannot be converted to String

¿Cómo soluciono este error? ¿Debo rehacer mi código de otra forma?

El método `guardar` utilizado forma parte de un *DAO*, es el siguiente:

```java
public void guardar(Estudiante e) {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmnt = null;

    try {
        con = dbcon.conectar();

        String sql = "INSERT INTO notas(nombre, matricula, nota) "
            + "VALUES(?, ?, ?)";

        pstmnt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        pstmnt.setString(1, e.getNombre());
        pstmnt.setString(2, e.getMatricula());
        pstmnt.setInt(3, e.getNota());

        pstmnt.execute();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        //System.out.println("Error al conectar a la BD");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al conectar a la BD");
    }
    finally {
        dbcon.desconectar(con);
    }
}
```

Comment: Agrego referencia de la pregunta ya hecha: [¿Cómo guardar parámetros de un método en una variable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/22931)

Answer (score 3):

La pregunta podría ser **"Problema en la asignación del retorno de función sobre una variable"**

Te la contestaría, pero no es el lugar apropiado. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

El título de una pregunta debe reflejar cuál es el problema que tienes. Una primera idea muy simple sería: **¿Por qué obtengo "incompatible types: void cannot be converted to String"?**. O una traducción de esto: **¿Por qué obtengo tipos incompatibles entre void y String?**. Quizás para dar un poco más de contexto, podrías colocar **¿Por qué hay incompatibilidad de tipos al ejecutar DAO.guardar?** de modo que resaltas dónde está tu problema.

Viéndolo desde otra arista, tu problema es sobre la asignación de una variable. Ello puede definir el contenido del título. Con esta base, un ejemplo sería: **¿Por qué no puedo asignar el resultado de mi método en una variable?**.